# Appropriate ways to 4K random read the same file concurrently in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Say, I'm going to use 30 threads(40 cores CPU) to 4K random read the same file and do some computing.

These 30 threads don't share any objects except for `fd`.

I initially wanted to `open` once before starting the threading staff, and then in each thread, `pread`(I knew the sequence of offsets in advance, and size of the sequence is 64, so there will be 64 `pread`), `pread`, `pread`...

But a shared `fd` seems to be deficient, because it will be used across 30 threads, hence a great lock-unlock time on `pread`(it's an atomic operation, so there will be lock-unlock in its implementation).

Is it better to `open` in each thread?

Comment: You say "These 30 threads don't share any objects.". Does this mean "I have decided not to share the fd between the threads like one normally would"?

Comment: So, one thread could handle all the reads and hand off buffers to a thread pool, but with I/O, I am very concerned that having many cores won't help much.

Comment: @thatotherguy I just noticed that `pread` is an atomic operation, so a shared `fd` won't cause any problems.

Comment: Right. The point of `pread` is to let everyone share the same fd without worrying about the current state of the cursor

Comment: The simpler and _faster_ way is to `mmap` the entire file [once]. Then each thread can be given offset pointer and range/length. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779978/memory-leak-how-do-i-allocate-memory-for-a-typdef-struct-passed-within-another/60780421#60780421 `mmap` in this way will have _much_ better performance than seeking/reading on different file descriptors

Comment: @CraigEstey The file is bigger than the memory, so `mmap` cannot be used.

Comment: When you say "memory", what are you talking about? Physical RAM?. If you're on a 64 bit machine, you _can_ map a much larger file. You _can_ map the entire file. I know because I've done it, per my linked answer, and other times I've done it. It can slow the system down due to page faults, so I have a version that maps the file in [more] manageable chunks [which I've done on 32 bit machines]. See my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173063/5382650 and also my answers that linked in that one.